# Show metabox only for homepage

Tags: php, metabox

I'll try to add metabox to homepage with setting fields, but something went wrong, help me please. The metabox don't appear in page editor, when i remove `if statement` it shows on all pages.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'metabox_homepage_videos');
function metabox_homepage_videos($post)
{
    if (is_front_page()):
        add_meta_box('metabox-homepage-videos', __("Homepage Videos"), 'metabox_homepage_videos_callback', 'page', 'side', 'low');
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_front_page()` is only for use on the front-end to tell if the 'main query' is for the front page. In a back end context you need to check if the current post ID (which is in the `$post` passed to your callback function) is the same ID that's set to be the front page.

So the if statement would look like this:

```
if ( $post->ID == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) :

endif;
```

Comment: still not working, it's a static page and uses `front-page.php` template

Comment: I added `global $post` and now working fine, thank you.

Comment: No need to add this global variable also
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'metabox_homepage_videos', 10, 2);
use this the 2 param is $post
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes